# Как сделать удаление и добавление класса для элемента интерфейса Выкл./Вкл. звука?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Делаю включение и выключение звука, но вот как менять картинку колоночки (включено) на колоночку выключенной - это сделал, но вот при повторном клике ВКЛЮЧЕНИИ непонятно.

Код пример выключения:

http://jsfiddle.net/tfh6hozr/

**ВСЕ СДЕЛАЛ! ПРОСТО НУЖНО БЫЛО СДЕЛАТЬ ELSE**

http://jsfiddle.net/tfh6hozr/1/

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, опубликуйте ваш ответ ответом/комментарием, Тогда его можно будет принять.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил сам, решение простое.

Посмотреть тут: http://jsfiddle.net/tfh6hozr/1/

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev посмотрите:

    $('.control-sound').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('on').toggleClass('off');
    });

Comment: Вариант, но мне нужен именно с if и else функционально важно!